# What does this means about a smile face of a person ? ほんわりとした笑顔を浮かべ

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

When reading, I met this expression about a smile, but not sure what does it means here (warm smile / gentle smile ??)

Much thanks if anyone can explain its meaning to me o/

**A はほんわりとした笑顔を浮かべ**、上機嫌な様子。

Answer (score 2):

A bit surprisingly 大辞泉 doesn't have an entry for ほんわり, but the following two may help

- [ふんわり](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B5%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A/#jn-197103) : 柔らかくふくらんださま。「―と仕上がったパン」 (linked is ふわり, ふんわり is an emphatic ver)
- [ほんわか](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%BB%E3%82%93%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B/#jn-206535)：心がなごんで、気持ちのよいさま。

ほんわりとした笑顔 means a mix of the above: *relaxed, soft-looking, feeling warmth*. Typical situations that come to my mind are when one is taking a bath or having a cup of tea.